# Paypal Payment gateway integration code=NO_BUSINESS

Tags: python, django, django-views, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate paypal payment gateway to my html page and its always returning "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later." in paypal sandbox page

```
    paypal_dict = {
        'buisness':"sb-xxxxxxxxxxx.business.example.com",
        'amount': cart_total_amount ,  
        'currency': 'INR',
        'receipt': 'order-item-number-' + str(order.id),
        'invoice_number': 'INVOICE_NO-' + str(order.id),  
        'notify_url': 'http://{}{}'.format(host, reverse("uwapp:paypal-ipn")),
        'return_url': 'http://{}{}'.format(host, reverse("uwapp:payment_completed")),
        'cancel_url': 'http://{}{}'.format(host, reverse("uwapp:payment_failed")),
    }

    # Generate the Razorpay payment button
    payment_button = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)

    return render(request, 'uwapp/checkout.html', {
        'payment_button': payment_button
    })
```